# Termination of all sessions followed by application end event

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, web-applications, extjs

We are encountering a strange phenomena in our production environment, every few hours the application kicks all users out by ending their sessions with Session_End event and fires Application_End event.
In our log, all the user's sessions are closed on the same mill-second.
We encountered this problem in our Test environment but only on rare occasions, and we could not duplicate this.
Everything else seems fine, other application running on this server works fine, there is no memory leak or CPU overuse. The application is based on ExtJS version 3.3, NHibnernate 3.2 and ASP.NET 4.0.
It doesn't seems like a Timeout error, some of the users worked for only several minutes before the session end.
Has anyone encountered similar problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why an application pool recycles (and thus ends all open sessions and ends the application). See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/05/16/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle.aspx for a complete overview.

We had a similar problem in a production environment once. The reason for the recycle was the virus scanner that touched the web.config on each scan which made the application pool recycle. Try to disable the virus scanner on the server or exclude the application directory in the virus scanner.

Altering the following files will also trigger an immediate restart of the application pool:

- web.config
- machine.config
- global.asax
- Anything in the bin directory or it's sub-directories

This post: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/14/433194.aspx gives you a way to catch the application end event with more detailed logging. This might help you to find the cause of the recycle.